# nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup a new site on my server, I've updated the nginx settings to redirect the new site, created the directories, setup the correct permissions and created the DNS entries on my domain.

However when I restart nginx I get the following error:

> nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "petproject" in
>   /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx-vhosts.conf:277 nginx: configuration file
>   /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed

Could someone tell me how to fix this? I have identical settings with a different domain and directory and it works fine so I can't quite pinpoint whats wrong here.

I have included my nginx.conf below.

```
server  {
        listen 217.23.14.107:80;
        server_name petproject.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/petproject.com_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/petproject_error.log;
        root /home/petproject/laravel/public;


        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js|ico|rar|gz|zip|pdf|tar|bmp|xls|doc|swf|mp3|avi|png|htc|txt|htc|flv$
            access_log   off;
            expires  7d;
        }

    location / {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass   http://petproject:8080;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                 

            client_max_body_size       10m;
            client_body_buffer_size    128k;

            proxy_connect_timeout      90;
            proxy_send_timeout         90;
            proxy_read_timeout         90;

            proxy_buffer_size          4k;
            proxy_buffers              4 32k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

        }


        # deny access to apache .htaccess files
        location ~ /\.ht
        {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: What should the `petproject` name in the `proxy_pass` statement resolve to?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, the `.com` was missing from the end of this value. The website is now being displayed. Please turn this into the answer.